# Uploading Image in Oracle Blob with Asp.net MVC 5 and show on html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, oracle11g

I have very new in asp.net seeking you help that, I am trying to upload image with the data of new user I can successfully add user information in database. But now I am stuck with uploading image. My form working perfectly passing all data to the *action* so I am starting from there:

```
public ActionResult SaveUser(string oid, string fname, string uname, string pass, string pass2, string bt, HttpPostedFileBase image)
{


    string iuser = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
    String fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    int fileSize = image.ContentLength;

    if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg")
    {
        Stream stream = image.InputStream;
        BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        byte[] bytes = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
    }


    if (pass == pass2)
    {
        if (bt == "0")
        {
            string packge = "tflhr.pro_new_user.insert_data";
            ds = new DataSet();
            ds = _clsDataAccess.package_user(packge, fname, uname, pass, iuser );

        }

    }

    return RedirectToAction("User", new { cpid = 0, bt = 0 });
}
```

In the action *image* containing images now how I can upload the image data in database here is my connection:

```
public DataSet package_user(string package, string fname, string pass, string uname, byte[] bytes, string iuser)
{
    conn = new OracleConnection(clsConnection.ConnectionSave);
    conn.Open();

    cmd = new OracleCommand(package, conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("cur_c1", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user_pass", OracleType.VarChar).Value = pass;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user_enid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = uname;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.Blob).Value = bytes;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("iuser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = iuser;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("euser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = iuser;


    oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    ds = new DataSet();

    conn.Close();
    oda.Fill(ds);
    return ds;

}
```

and store procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TFLHR.pro_new_user as
procedure insert_data (cur_c1 out t_cursor, user_name in varchar2, user_pass in varchar2,
user_enid in varchar2, bytes in blob, iuser in varchar2, euser in varchar2)
is
code varchar2(5);
begin
select nvl(max(to_number(user_text)),0)+1 into code from tflhr.t_user;
insert into tflhr.t_user (oid, user_text, user_name, user_pass, user_enid,image, iuser, euser,user_path)
values
('USERx'||lpad(code,5,'0'), lpad(code,5,'0'), user_name, user_pass, user_enid, bytes, iuser, euser, lpad(code,5,'0'));
open cur_c1 for
select '1' from dual;
        commit;
    end insert_data;
end;
/
```

And I got Exception

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dADiH.gif)
How I change this parameter to upload image. Plz help me and short out if there any mistake. Thank You

Comment: Are you want to pass image data into stored procedure from `package_user`? I think you should add `OracleDbType.Blob` parameter for your SP to insert byte array from the image, then in viewmodel set the `<img>` source with virtual path of the image.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay. Plz check that i have change my  code and getting this error *An exception of type 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException' occurred in System.Data.OracleClient.dll but was not handled in user code*

Comment: Can you provide exception details (also with inner exception) and stack trace? I suspected you're using wrong parameter name in `cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.Blob).Value = bytes;`. If you can provide stored procedure codes, it's much better.

Comment: I have added store procedure and Exception. Plz let me know if further information need

Answer (score 0):

The exception *multiple instances of named argument in list* occurs because you're adding the same parameter name twice as shown in this snippet (and the parameter name is also wrong corresponding to parameter data type):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_pass", OracleType.VarChar).Value = pass;
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_enid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = uname;

// user_name parameter used twice here, the exception thrown
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.Blob).Value = bytes;
```

You should add `bytes` parameter name instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("cur_c1", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_name", OracleType.VarChar).Value = fname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_pass", OracleType.VarChar).Value = pass;
cmd.Parameters.Add("user_enid", OracleType.VarChar).Value = uname;
cmd.Parameters.Add("bytes", OracleType.Blob).Value = bytes; // problem fixed
cmd.Parameters.Add("iuser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = iuser;
cmd.Parameters.Add("euser", OracleType.VarChar).Value = iuser;
```

Note that you can use `AddWithValue` to simplify the parameter definitions, but make sure they're passed with proper data types.

Additionally, you should pass method parameters in proper order:

```
ds = _clsDataAccess.package_user(packge, fname, pass, uname, bytes, iuser);
```

because the method signature looks like this:

```
public DataSet package_user(string package, string fname, string pass, string uname, byte[] bytes, string iuser)
```

Comment: ok! That problem is solved now  I am getting this error now *{"ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested\n"}* further help plz

Comment: You can see similar issue [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01460_unimplemented_or_unreasonable_conversion_requested.htm). It related to ODP.NET version you're using, not the query string. Try update to newer ODP.NET version.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: My ODP.NET Version is 12